# Group values with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i hope you can help me;

I have this xsl code:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//DataSet">
      <xsl:sort select="@wert"/>
      <xsl:sort select="@key"/>
        <tr>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="@orig_pk"/></td>
             <td><xsl:copy-of select="original"/></td>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="@dup_pk"/></td>
             <td><xsl:copy-of select="duplikat"/></td>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="@key"/></td>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="@wert"/></td>
        </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

The code generates a HTML Table with the correct values. Now I'd like to group these Values by `key` and render a new `<tr>` above each group:

```
<tr>
 <th class="data_header" align="left" nowrap="nowrap"><xsl:text>Schlüssel: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@key"/></th>
</tr>
```

But as our system is only supporting XSLT 1.0 I can't use the `<xsl:for-each-group>` and as I'm only able to do easy things in xsl I'm unable to do this with the `Muenchian method`.

Now my question is; can someone help me to realize this and also explain it a little bit?

Thanky you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you show you input XML and the output you expect in this case? Don't be afraid of the Muenchian Grouping method. It is worth the effort to try and learn if you are using XSLT 1.0. See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html for a very good explanation of how it works.

Comment: @TimC Thank you for your encouragement, I managed it by my own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- this key allows us to quickly get a set of DataSet elements where @key equals to specified value -->
    <xsl:key name="dataset-by-key" match="DataSet" use="@key"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- iterate over all DataSet elements and select only those that are first among others with the same @key value, i.e. tricky way to do grouping = Muenchian grouping -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//DataSet[generate-id() = generate-id(key('dataset-by-key', @key)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="@key"/>
            <tr>
                <th class="data_header" align="left" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <xsl:text>Schlussel: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@key"/>
                </th>
            </tr>

            <!-- according to definition of this key, key('dataset-by-key', @key) returns all DataSet elements where @key equals to specified value -->
            <xsl:for-each select="key('dataset-by-key', @key)">
                <xsl:sort select="@wert"/>
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@orig_pk"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:copy-of select="original"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@dup_pk"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:copy-of select="duplikat"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@wert"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, did it exactly as you, but forgot to post it ^^

Comment: So, you can see that it's easy!